# How can i controll parent Html from @Output value to my parrent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-forms

Here i have two component HrComponent And appcomponent  How can i controll `IsBoolean`  from my HrComponent

**HrComponent**

```
 @Input()LoginName: string;
    IsBoolean: boolean = false;

 @Output()BooleanExp: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    onSelectChange() {
        this.BooleanExp.emit(this.IsBoolean);
    }
```

**appcomponent**

```
 Name: string = "Hello"
 <div>

        <HrSelector [LoginName]="Name">
            <span>{{LoginName}}</span>
            <div *ngIf="IsBoolean">
                <p>This is Special Div</p>
            </div>
        </HrSelector>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
 <HrSelector [LoginName]="Name" (BooleanExp)="onChange($event)">
        <span>{{LoginName}}</span>
        <div *ngIf="IsBoolean">
            <p>This is Special Div</p>
        </div>
 </HrSelector>
```

In your ts, define the `onChange` method:

```
onChange(event) {
    this.IsBoolean = event;
}
```